# How to rename multiple columns in oracle using one Alter table statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, alter

The only thing I found is renaming one column at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name;
```

I read Oracle documentations, and couldn't get the answer for many columns at a time .

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljrenamecolumnstatement.html

Comment: Why can't you just issue multiple statements? How are you picking which columnes to rename, and what to call them? (You've linked to the JavaDB docs; the Oracle RDBMS version [is here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877); but you can still only rename one per `alter` statement.)

Comment: The SQL Standard (and, with that, Oracle DB and perhaps most if not all other SQL dialects) doesn't define an ALTER TABLE statement where you can change multiple column names in a single shot. So, you will have to write your own code (or find code already written by someone else) if you need to automate this type of action. WHY though? Why do you have to rename so many columns that doing them one at a time is not feasible for you?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to rename multiple table columns in a single command, as of Oracle 18c.

The [Oracle 18c SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) includes the below diagram to illustrate how the `RENAME_COLUMN_CLAUSE` of the `ALTER TABLE` command works.  Unfortunately, almost every column property can be modified in groups, except for renaming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user_tab_columns` dictionary view as a data source within a cursor   for a loop statement

```
declare
  v_table_name varchar2(40):='mytable';
begin
  for c in ( select from user_tab_columns where table_name = upper(v_table_name) )
  loop
    execute immediate ('ALTER TABLE '||c.table_name||' RENAME COLUMN '||c.column_name
                                                   ||' TO new_'||c.column_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I suspect "old_name" and "new_name" in the OP's post were generic - he may want to rename "baseball" to "MLB" and "basketball" to "NBA" for example (using US names). The solution you propose can be adapted for this more generic understanding of the problem, but it WILL be more complicated.

Comment: @mathguy you may be right, but we have not enough clue about the renaming strategy.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME COLUMN old_column_name1 TO new_column_name1,
RENAME COLUMN old_column_name2 TO new_column_name2,
...,
RENAME COLUMN old_column_nameN TO new_column_nameN;
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works in Oracle?  Others say you cant do it.

Comment: On version 21c, this command raises the error "ORA-23290: This operation may not be combined with any other operation".